# Dropdown values should be selected using AngularJs ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

on click i am creating row similar to the one added in the image.
every time i would be having same row with same modal.

[image]
How can i select the selected values from a row

Comment: How can we guide without seeing your code ?

Comment: There is no image... please add some code or create a plnkr

Answer (score 1):

```
Its just a sample to get to your need.

.js file..

angular.module('nonStringSelect', [])
.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.model = { id: 2 };
})
.directive('convertToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        return parseInt(val, 10);
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
        return '' + val;
      });
    }
  };
});
```